# cannot run xtext without eclipse (as jar)

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to use Xtext without eclipse as described in this post: http://zarnekow.blogspot.de/2010/06/how-to-deploy-xtext-standalone.html. Unfortunately, I can't get the created .jar file to run.

I have created a run configuration. It uses a Wrapper class as its Main class, which calls the Mwe2Launcher.main method. (Using Mwe2Launcher as the main class didn't work for me).
This, as well as exporting the project to a runnable jar file, so far worked well. However, now I cannot get the jar file to run. 
I use

```
java -jar exported.jar org.example.mydsl.GenerateMydsl
```

with org.example.mydsl.GenerateMydsl.mwe2 being the workflow file that I usually run as MWE2 Workflow when running Xtext in Eclipse (successfully, btw).
But I receive the following Errors within my output:

```
7098 ERROR Generator          - java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\org.example.mydsl\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path)
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\org.example.mydsl\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.mergeManifest(Generator.java:418)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generateManifestRt(Generator.java:385)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:71)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:35)
        at org.example.domainmodel.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\org.example.mydsl\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.mergeManifest(Generator.java:404)
        ... 13 more
7098 INFO  Workflow           - Done.
```

It's looking for the manifest file in \org.example.mydsl\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF. However, in the jar, the META-INF folder is located directly in the root.

Does anybody have an idea about what I might be doing wrong or what else I could try?
Would be grateful for help.

Comment: I was under the impression that the MWE2 workflow was required to generate Java classes and some other stuff from your Xtext grammar. You then use the generated classes and any of your own code that you've written to parse a file written in your language and generate more code from that. This second stage is done with the <YourLanguage>StandaloneSetup.java (eventually extends org.eclipse.xtext.ISetup) file. Are you trying to do the first or second thing? I would expect you would run the MWE2 in eclipse, then export a JAR with the result and do the second thing I mentioned above.